# Coding Theory: Irreducible Polynomial divides x^m+1

Tags: finite-fields, coding-theory, binary

I need some help please.  This is for a coding theory course dealing with Galois Fields $GF(2^r)$, the problem is stated as follows:

Show that if $h(x) \in \mathbb{F}_2[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$, then $h(x)$ divides $1+x^m$ for some $m \leq 2^m-1$.

So far I have $0 \leq m<2^n-1$, there are $2^n-1$ possible non-zero remainders for

$$x^m+1 = a(x)h(x)+r(x)$$

However, when $r(x)=0$, how does that specifically imply that $m=2^n-1$?  Is there another route to follow here?  How can I show that $x^{2^n-1} \equiv 1 \mod(h(x))$?

Comment: This is false if $h(x)=x$. As you’ve notified, there are a maximum number of remainders. By pigeonhole, you have $x^a+1\equiv x^b+1 \mod h(x)$. Subtracting and dividing my $x^a$ gives the desired result.

Comment: So simple if you put it like that.  Thank you very much.